# What layouts am I to use to get the GUI I want?

Tags: java, swing, layout, jpanel, grid-layout

I'm completely at a lose for which layouts I should be using to create the GUI I want for my program.

On the left hand side, I'd like my panel to have three buttons in it, going down vertically. On the right hand side, I will have another panel, that will be my main panel, where all the information is displayed, depending on what button is pressed.

I literally have no idea which layouts I should use, and I'm completely stumped as to how I get my GUI to look like this:[image]

Here's my code at the moment:

```
        public void addComponentsToPane(Container pane) {

        JPanel innerPane = new JPanel();
        JPanel outerPane = new JPanel();
        outerPane.setBackground(Color.yellow);

        pane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        JButton btnAdd = new JButton("Add");
        JButton btnEdit = new JButton("Edit");
        JButton btnMovements = new JButton("Movements");

        innerPane.add(btnAdd, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        innerPane.add(btnEdit, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        innerPane.add(btnMovements, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        pane.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));
        pane.add(innerPane);
        pane.add(outerPane);
    }
```

Which returns this:

[image]

As you can see, it looks nothing like I'd want it to be and I don't know what to do.

My buttons are incorrect and I'm possibly approaching this the wrong way.

My question is, how can I approach this problem the correct way, in that I can create a GUI with the correct layouts and get it to look like the first picture?

Thank you.

Comment: The proxy server at work is blocking the images, so I can't see exactly what you want.  However, you can generally accomplish good results by nesting various layout managers in Swing.  I would considering using a GridLayout for the buttons, nested in a panel with a BorderLayout, with the panel containing the buttons added to NORTH, and an empty label added to CENTER to take up the remaining space.  Then add that to the another panel using a BorderLayout (WEST), with your outerPane in CENTER.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content pane of a JFrame uses a BorderLayout by default. I would keep that layout.

Then you create a "left" panel and add it to BorderLayout.LINE_START. This area will contain your buttons. Then you can set the layout manager of this panel to GridBagLayout. Create a second panel using a GridLayout with the components aligned vertically. Add the button to this panel. Add this panel to the "left" panel using:

```
leftPanel.add(buttonPanel, new GridBagConstraints);
```

Then you create another panel and add it to BorderLayout.CENTER. This is your colored panel.

So the basic logic is:

```
JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel( new GridLayout(...) );
buttonPanel.add(...);

JPanel leftPanel = new JPanel( new GridBagLayout() );
leftPanel.add(buttonPanel, new GridBagConstraints());

JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel();
center.setBackground( Color.YELLOW );

frame.add(leftPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
frame.add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

If you want your buttons to be larger than the default then you would do something like:

```
button.setMargin( new Insets(20, 20, 20, 20) );
```

Read the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information and examples of each layout manager.

If you want extra space on the panel containing the buttons, then you need to use an `EmptyBorder`. The Swing tutorial also contains a section on `How to Use Borders` you can read for working examples.

Experiment and learn to nest panels to get your desired effect.